# Override app.get('*', func) route in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, passport.js

I have an Angular app running alongside a NodeJS server.

This code in my server.js file:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

require('./server/routes/routes')(app, passport);
```

Seems to be preventing any GET requests to my api, for example:

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
  app.get('/api/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
      res.status(200).json(req.user);
  });
```

When the exported /api/profile handler is changed to a post the request works.

Should the route not overwrite the initial handler? How to achieve this? Can I serve the app for all routes excluding beginning with '/api'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `app.get('*')` so it becomes the last route that gets declared:

```
require('./server/routes/routes')(app, passport);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Express checks route handlers in order of their declaration, not in order of their specificity (how well they match a particular request).